# How can I install lxml into inkscape in windows?

Tags: windows-10, installation, python, inkscape, libxml

I have `inkscape v0.92.2` in Windows 10. and I want to use the `Measure Path` function.

When I do it, I see this error:

[image]

If I go to the suggested path, http://cheeseshop.python.org/pypi/lxml/, and I click "Download files", I can see this:

[image]

## Questions:

a) If I have **not** installed Python manually, how do I know what version (27, 33, etc.) does `inkscape` use?

b) Okey... I can download a `.whl` file. But provided I dit **not** manually install any python, how do I make `inkscape` to find the `whl` when invoking `Measure Path`? What's the next step after downloading?